# How to remove separation between a table and horizontal line?

Tags: html, css

I have a table and below the table I have a horizontal line (`<hr>`). There is a vertical separation between the table and horizontal line and I would like to remove it. How can I do it? Does it comes from the table or the horizontal line or from both? By the way, I see it only in the IE. In Mozilla and Chrome there is not vertical separation between the table and the line.

Comment: `hr { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` didn't work ? If you just want to put a bottom line to the table, you could `table { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }`.

Comment: Post a link and we will be able to help you much easier.

Answer (score 2):

First of all inspect your blocks with Firebug:
https://addons.mozilla.org/hu/firefox/addon/firebug/

With this you will be able to see that which element has padding or margin. After you've found it simply give it a margin:0; property.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `<hr>` tag is a [block element](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/), try setting `display:inline`;